# laravel5.3 job (catch exception when sending callbacks), delay not working

Tags: php, exception, queue, delay, laravel-5.3

I work with jobs to send back webrequests (GET) to urls a user defined.
To save load of my server I would like to disable the API access of user after 5 retrys (which all failed).
Here's the full code of my job (excluding imports & some code parts that are unnecessary (disabling API access etc.).

```
use Exception;

class SendGetCallback implements ShouldQueue
{
use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $address;
public $new_transaction;

//Address $address, Transaction $new_transaction
public function __construct ($address, $new_transaction)
{
    $this->address = $address;
    $this->new_transaction = $new_transaction;
}

public function handle()
{
    Log::info("run: " . $this->attempts());
    if ($this->attempts() <= 5) {

        if ($this->attempts() > 1) {
            Log::info("retry part");

            //retry to send the callback
            try{
                Log::info("try part");

                //prepare webrequest

                if ($res->getStatusCode() != 200 || $res->getBody()->getContents() != "*ok*")
                    throw new Exception('callback url not reachable');

            }
            //if job failed again, release job after 300 seconds
            catch(Exception $e){
                Log::info("catch part");
                $this->release(300);
            }
        }
        //first run of job, just process normal
        else{

            //prepare webrequest

            if ($res->getStatusCode() != 200 || $res->getBody()->getContents() != "*ok*")
                throw new Exception('callback url not reachable');

        }
    }
    //disable API access and inform user
    else{
        Log::info("disable access");
        Mail::to($this->address->user->email)->send(new ApiAccessDisabled($this->address->user, $this->address->merchant_access));

        $merchant_access = MerchantAccess::where('id', $this->address->merchant_access->id)->first();

        $merchant_access->update([
            'is_online' => false,
            ]);
    }
}

public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
    Log::info("failed called!");
}
}
```

For some reason the delay I use didn't work I think. The jobs just runs down without waiting.

Here's a part of the logfile:

```
[2017-01-01 18:25:02] local.INFO: run: 2  
[2017-01-01 18:25:02] local.INFO: retry part
[2017-01-01 18:25:02] local.INFO: try part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:03] local.INFO: catch part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:14] local.INFO: run: 3  
[2017-01-01 18:25:14] local.INFO: retry part 
[2017-01-01 18:25:14] local.INFO: try part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:14] local.INFO: catch part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:24] local.INFO: run: 4  
[2017-01-01 18:25:24] local.INFO: retry part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:24] local.INFO: try part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:24] local.INFO: catch part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:35] local.INFO: run: 5  
[2017-01-01 18:25:35] local.INFO: retry part
[2017-01-01 18:25:35] local.INFO: try part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:35] local.INFO: catch part  
[2017-01-01 18:25:45] local.INFO: run: 6  
[2017-01-01 18:25:45] local.INFO: disable access
```

Any idea where things go wrong?
Here's how the handle() method should work:

-->check if the run of the get request fails, for example when webserver of user is offline (throws exception) ->if yes set delay for job in 5 minutes

-->if job was runned for 5 times the api access should be disabled (working fine)

Comment: What class are you extending? I guess `Command`. I think the `release` is for `Queue`

Comment: May be if you can provide the whole class may be helpful

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam I haven't edited code of the release() function. What code you mean, should I show you?

Comment: Not the `release` function. The `handle` function's file, the whole class code.

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam I updated my first post, now including nearly the whole job class (excluding just some Model includes, preparing webrequest etc.)

Comment: Did u try using `$this->delay(300)` ?

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam Using $this->delay(300) makes the job run twice and then it stops...nothing happend after 5 minutes. Here's the output of the logfile. `[2017-01-02 15:00:06] local.INFO: run: 2  
[2017-01-02 15:00:06] local.INFO: retry part  
[2017-01-02 15:00:06] local.INFO: try part  
[2017-01-02 15:00:06] local.INFO: catch part`